# Android Studio can't install android 12 when run with Installation Options - APK from app bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-12

I use installation Options - Deploy - APK from app bundle becasuse of PAD(Play Asset Delivery).

Android 10, 11 build & run works well, but in android 12, install failed.

(But Build SUCCESSFUL)

[image]

and  install failed message

```
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session 223924615 with command cmd package install-commit 223924615.
Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: 
Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl223924615.tmp/split_config.xxhdpi.apk (at Binary XML file line #0): 
/data/app/vmdl223924615.tmp/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk (at Binary XML file line #0): Failed to read manifest from /data/app/vmdl223924615.tmp/split_assetPack.apk'
```

(My assets pack name is assetPack)

version info

- android studio : [image]
- target SDK : 30
- min SDK : 26
- gradle version : 4.0.2
- build tools version : 30.0.2
- kotlin version : 1.4.10

Answer (score -1):

```
 implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0-alpha05'
```

Put this line in **build.gradle** and sync...

work for me....

Comment: Thanks to your answer! but It didn't work for me ...

Comment: I have a folder called Gradle scripts and inside it there are several build.gradle in which I would place this line, thanks!